# Android query phonenumber to obtain rawcontactID

Tags: android, contacts, phone-number

I would like to query on phonenumber to obtain the rawcontactID.

The only thing I know of the contact is the given phonenumber, but for my function I need to have the rawcontactID. I got a working code but now I did use 2 seperate queries. What I would like to have is 1 query that can do both just to save some query time.

my code:

```
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Phone.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));       
    String[] columns = new String[]{Phone.CONTACT_ID, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER, Phone._ID };     
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, columns, null, null, null); 

if(cursor!=null) { 
    int clenght = cursor.getCount();
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){ 
     //contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME)); 
     id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.CONTACT_ID)); 

    } 
    cursor.close(); 
}

Cursor pCur = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID}, ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID+" = "+ id, null, null); 
if(pCur!=null) { 
    int clenght = pCur.getCount();
    while(pCur.moveToNext()){ 
     //contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME)); 
     id = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID)); 

    } 
    pCur.close(); 
}
```

thanks in advance

Edit:

My code above works fine, but I am still looking for increasing speed for large number of contacts. Therefore I will give a bounty if someone comes with a solution to combine my  queries.

Comment: do you need Single RAW_CONTACT_ID or Multiple RAW_CONTACT_ID?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, a single RAW_CONTACT_ID is suitible for my application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private String[] getRawContactIdFromNumber(String givenNumber){
        List<String> rawIds = new ArrayList<String>();
        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.RAW_CONTACT_ID},ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + "='"+ givenNumber +"'",null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

        while (phones.moveToNext())
        {
          rawIds.add( phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.RAW_CONTACT_ID)));
          Log.v("contacts","Given Number: " + givenNumber + "Raw ID: " +rawIds.get(rawIds.size() - 1));
        }
        phones.close();
        String[] ret = new String[0];

        return rawIds.toArray(ret);
    }
```

Edited to only include the raw id in the cursor for efficiency. Also changed return type to array in case multiple contacts have the same number.

Comment: Ok i've tested your sample code, and I did included some values to the query. And it works good and fast :D thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
String phonenumber = "input your phone number";
        Cursor pCur = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] { ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID,
                        Phone.CONTACT_ID }, Phone.NUMBER + " = " + phonenumber,
                null, null);


if (pCur != null) {
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                    String contactID = pCur.getString(pCur
                            .getColumnIndex(Phone.CONTACT_ID));
                    String Rowid = pCur.getString(pCur
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID));
                    Log.e("RAW_CONTACT_ID", Rowid);
                    Log.e("CONTACT_ID", contactID);
                }
                pCur.close();
            }
```

Now you can get Both `CONTACT_ID` & `RAW_CONTACT_ID` in single query.

Comment: I did test it, and the pCur.count is always 0, you got any idea?

Comment: have you check input phone number is inside in phone?

Comment: I did add a new contact with phonenumber, and I did also added the number in the query, but still the mcount of the pCur is still 0

Comment: have you check in phone or emulator?

Comment: I am testing on a galaxy nexus ics

Comment: i have test on samsung galaxy ace[2.3.3] phone.. and now i will try android 4.0 emulator then let you know.

Comment: On my wildfire with android 2.x it does return mCount = 0